# Filtering JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an output from an API, consisting of a list of elements like the following :

```
{
  "data": [
  {
    "url": "https://parktheater.yesplan.nl/api/event/7036825857-1426512948",
    "id": "7036825857-1426512948",
    "owner": {
    "url": "https://parktheater.yesplan.nl/api/user/365891073-1365159547",
    "id": "365891073-1365159547",
    "name": "Klaas Seelen"
  },
  "name": "Ernst, Bobbie en de rest",
  "group": {
    "url": "https://parktheater.yesplan.nl/api/group/7036832513-1426512948",
    "id": "7036832513-1426512948",
    "name": "Wij willen water show",
    "_type": "group"
  },
  "starttime": "2016-05-01T16:00:00+02:00",
  "endtime": "2016-05-01T18:00:00+02:00",
  "locations": [
    {
      "url": "https://parktheater.yesplan.nl/api/location/383044097-1365160415",
      "id": "383044097-1365160415",
      "name": "Grote Zaal",
      "_type": "location"
    }
  ]
}
```

This data is provided to me as a string of JSON encoded data, which I stored in a variable `$nextevents`.

I would like to filter things out, to keep only certain properties of each record :

- Name ("ernst, bobbie en de rest")
- Group name ("Wij willen water show")
- Location type ("Grote zaal")
- starttime ("2016-05-01T16:00:00+02:00")
  How do I manage that?

Comment: What programming language are we even talking about? PHP, Javascript, C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to filter the data :

```
$json_data = json_decode($nextevents);
$filtered_data = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($json_data); $i++){
   $item = $json_data[$i];
   $filtered_data[$i] = array(
      "name" => $item["name"],
      "group_name" => $item["group"]["name"],
      "location_name" => $item["locations"][0]["name"],
      "start_time" => $item["starttime"]
   );
}
```

And then you can use it. For example, if you want to output it in a way similar to your example :

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($filtered_data); $i++){
   $item = $filtered_data[$i];
   echo "Name : ".$item["name"].", ".
      "Group name : ".$item["group_name"].", ".
      "Location : ".$item["location_name"].", ".
      "Start time : ".$item["start_time"].
      "\n");
}
```

I think the general idea is that to filter the data, the most practical way is to rebuild another object, keeping only what you want.

Comment: And how do i show the results? i'm sorry i am such a n00b on scripting

Comment: It all depends what you mean by "show" but the basic idea is the second part of my answer

Comment: I already given an upvote but i dont have anough reputation. also am i still working on getting it done. i have edited my post with more scripts and information

Comment: i'm sorry i didnt know that i would take so long to edit my post and that you reply that quickly. now everything is edited maybe you could help me further

Comment: Ok I understand what you want. I have edited my answer. You can replace everything you have put after your commented line ("//in $nextevents is now the json output") by this code

Comment: Thanks for marking the answer as accepted. I will clean up your question, to remove all parts that don't relate to the problem. I actually think that your question is not related to APIs, Ajax, or anything except just filtering an array in PHP. Cleaning up the question will make it easier to understand for future readers

Comment: i didn't do anything. But to be clear the json data which is showed is collected from an API. but i understand that is my problem that isn't relevant. is it oke the way i edited it?

Comment: There is some Syntax Error at line Number 10 in 1st part (array is not close properly).